# How to raise ActiveResource ResourceInvalid exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activeresource

I want to raise an Active Resource exception manually from RSpec and I am trying to doing something like this-

```
ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid.new(422, "Error Message")
```

Though I am able to raise ActiveRecord exception but ActiveResource is not raising.

I see the `initialize` method of `ActiveResource` is expecting two arguments.

```
def initialize(response, message = nil)
      @response = response
      @message  = message
end
```

I guess the issue is in sending the `response` parameter.

Comment: In your example code, you are creating a new instance of `ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound`, but you are not actually [`raise`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-raise)-ing it. Please show your full RSpec example, including the current output (or error message) and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
expect { 
  raise ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound.new(404, 'Error Message') 
}.to raise_error(ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound, 404, 'Error Message')
```

Note the `raise` and the curly brackets.